# Orchard - save list of elements on form submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

Basically i have a editor view where i have a few fields and a list, located in admin -> teacher -> edit

**File.cshtml**

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>@T("Details")</legend>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, T("First name"))
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName, T("Last name"))
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Gender, T("Gender"))
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, genderSelectListItems, "Select gender...")
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
@{
    var i = 0;
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Availability)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Availability, daysSelectList, "Select day to add...")
    <input type="button" id="addDay" value="Add" />
    <ul id="daysList">
        @foreach (var day in Model.Availability)
        {
            <li>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Availability[i].Interval)
            </li>
            i++;
        }
    </ul>
}
</fieldset>
```

Whenever i submit the data, only the fields get saved. The list is never saved, even though fiddler shows that the data is sent back to the server

My models are:
**TeacherPartRecord**

```
public class TeacherPartRecord : ContentPartRecord
{
    public TeacherPartRecord()
    {
        TeacherData = new List<TeacherDataRecord>();
    }

    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<TeacherDataRecord> TeacherData { get; set; }
}
```

**TeacherPart** - this file is almost the same as TeacherPartRecord so i truncated it, showing only the difference

```
public class TeacherPart : ContentPart<TeacherPartRecord>
{
      ................  
    public IList<AvailabilityRecord> Availability
    {
        get { return Record.TeacherData.Select(r => r.AvailabilityRecord).ToList(); }
    }
}
```

**TeacherDataRecord**

```
public class TeacherDataRecord
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual TeacherPartRecord TeacherPartRecord { get; set; }
    public virtual AvailabilityRecord AvailabilityRecord { get; set; }
}
```

**AvailabilityRecord**

```
public class AvailabilityRecord
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Day Day { get; set; }
    public virtual string Interval { get; set; }
}
```

and **TeacherPartDriver**

```
public class TeacherPartDriver : ContentPartDriver<TeacherPart>
{
    //GET
    protected override DriverResult Editor(TeacherPart part, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        return ContentShape("Parts_Teacher_Edit", () => 
            shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(TemplateName: "Parts/Teacher", Model: BuildEditorViewModel(part), Prefix: Prefix));
    }

    //POST
    protected override DriverResult Editor(TeacherPart part, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        var viewModel = new TeacherEditViewModel();
        updater.TryUpdateModel(viewModel, Prefix, null, null);
        _teacherService.UpdateTeacher(viewModel, part);
        return Editor(part, shapeHelper);
    }
}
```

**BuildEditorViewModel** only maps properties from *TeacherPart* to *TeacherEditViewModel*, which is identical with *TeacherPart*

The POST Editor method never receives the data from Availability (**part.Availability** is the same as previously, new data is not received)

I inserted a few entries in the database manually because i can't add a list of type Availability from the edit page, even though the other content (first name, last name, gender) is created

I would like to know how/when does the binding occur, or maybe some suggestions on how i could solve this issue.

I should mention that my c#/MVC experience is 6 months and my orchard experience is about 2 weeks so i'm still learning.
All i hope is that i stated my problem clearly and there is someone that can help. 
Thank you for your time

**EDIT**
As i can see, the values are bound

```
<input id="Teacher_Availability_0__Interval" name="Teacher.Availability[0].Interval" type="text" value="14-20">
<input id="Teacher_Availability_1__Interval" name="Teacher.Availability[1].Interval" type="text" value="12-18">
```

and fiddler shows the data is getting sent

[Fiddler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6cZT.png)

so i guess that something wrong happens right after the data is sent and before being received by the server or maybe my models are wrong

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls for a collection. You need a `for` loop of `EditorTemplate`. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)

Comment: But he uses and increments a counter nonetheless, so the html should be valid. @Ionuț can you confirm the rendered html for #daysList is valid?

Comment: Yes, the html is correct, and the data is sent back to the server. And that is the moment when something somewhere goes wrong and i don't get what
I will edit my post showing fiddler

Comment: You said that *TeacherEditViewModel* is identical to TeacherPart, which doesn't have a setter on *Availability*. That might be a problem.
If it's not 100% identical, can you please post the ViewModel too?

Comment: I repeat again - do not use a `foreach` loop. And you have multiple other issues such as `Availability` does not have a setter, so its values cannot be set by the `DefaultModelBinder` and you you have a dropdownlist for `Availability` and you cannot bind a `<select>` element to a collection of complex objects.

Comment: @Xceno The ViewModel is
 
    `public class TeacherEditViewModel  
 {
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public Gender Gender { get; set; }

  public IList<AvailabilityRecord> Availability { get; set; }
 }`

Stephen, i will try what you said and get back to you

Comment: @StephenMuecke adding a setter to the `Availability` and a for loop does not solve the issue. Still the same result. As for the DropDown, ignore it for a second, first i want to make it work and after that, add more elements to the list.

Comment: You cant 'ignore' the dropdownlist - its binding to property `Avaliability` do if its value is say `1` then the `DefaultModelBinder` will try to do `model.Avaliability = 1;` which of course fails. You need to delete it from the view. And adding the setter is essential because without it, binding will also fail.

Comment: It seems that there were no issues. all i had to do was map the part to the ViewModel in the service and update/create database entries. Thank you both for your time. VS debugger wasn't showing the updated data until i wrote the mappings. So for that matter, i still don't get it how it works